# adding items to a combobox in the datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

ive got a simple datagrid made out of comboboxes and textboxes. the last field named "cost" is a textbox,result of the combination of the comboboxes selected. Here's the xaml:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" x:Name="myGrid"  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Routes,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Sequenza N°"/>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn Width="100" x:Name="Product" 
        SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Product, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Header="Product" 
        DisplayMemberPath="{Binding Product}"  >
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn>  
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn Width="100" x:Name="Quality" 
        SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Quality, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Header="Cestello" 
        DisplayMemberPath="{Binding Quality}"  >
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Cost, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Header="Cost"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

And the code behind is a class called Routing which defines a list of values and used propertychanged to change the Cost textbox value.

```
namespace weblego
{
public partial class Prepare : Window
{

    public List<Routing> Routes { get; set; }
    public Prepare()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Routes = new List<Routing>()
            {
            new Routing() { Product = "triangolo"}
            };
        string[] stazioni = { "stazione1", "stazione2", "stazione3" };
        string[] qualita = { "low", "medium", "high" };
        Product.ItemsSource = stazioni;
        Quality.ItemsSource = qualita;
        myGrid.ItemsSource = Routes;
    }
}
public class Routing : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string product;
    public string Product
    {
        get { return product; }
        set
        {
            if (product != value)
            {
                product = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(value);
            }
        }
    }

    private string quality;
    public string Quality
    {
        get { return quality; }
        set
        {
            if (quality != value)
            {
                quality = value;
                UpdateCost();
                OnPropertyChanged(value);
            }
        }
    }


    private double cost;
    public double Cost
    {
        get { return cost; }
        set
        {
            if (cost != value)
            {
                cost = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Cost");
            }
        }
    }

    public void UpdateCost()
    {
        double qualityMultiple = 1;
        switch (Quality)
        {
            case "high":
                qualityMultiple = 1.5;
                break;
            case "medium":
                qualityMultiple = 1;
                break;
            case "low":
                qualityMultiple = 0.5;
                break;
        }

        switch (Product)
        {
            case "stazione1":
                Cost = 10 * qualityMultiple;
                break;
            case "stazione2":
                Cost = 15 * qualityMultiple;
                break;
            case "stazione3":
                Cost = 12.5 * qualityMultiple;
                break;
        }

    }

    // Create the OnPropertyChanged method to raise the event
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
}
```

everything works fine,but i made a planning error. the last field in the xaml called "Cost" is supposed to be a combobox,not a textbox,and must be filled with values coming from a database. so the XAML should become:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Width="100" x:Name="Cost" 
        SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Cost, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Header="Cost" 
        DisplayMemberPath="{Binding Cost}" />
```

And the code behind should let me change the itemsource on the Cost element in some way.

```
    private List<string> cost;
    public List<string> Cost
    {
        get { return cost; }
        set
        {
            if (cost != value)
            {
                cost = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Cost");
            }
        }
    }
        public void UpdateCost()
    {
        if(Quality=="high" && Product == "stazione1")
        {
            Cost.Add("abc");
            Cost.Add("def");
        }

    }
```

But when i do this,i get a System.NullReferenceException' saying the Cost is null. How can i change the itemsource of the last combobox depending on the selected values in the other fields of the row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, You're going to need two things for your combo box to work. First, the list of costs or ItemsSource for your combobox. The next is your actual selectedCost.

Here is a working example:

xaml:

```
<Window x:Name="window"
        x:Class="Sandpit.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Sandpit"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" x:Name="myGrid"  ItemsSource="{Binding Routes}" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Sequenza N°" />
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Product">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Product}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableProducts}"
                                  SelectedValue="{Binding Product, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Quality">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Quality}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableQuality}"
                                  SelectedValue="{Binding Quality, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Quality">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Cost}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableCosts}"
                                  SelectedValue="{Binding Cost, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Window>
```

Window code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;


namespace Sandpit
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Routing> routes;
        public ObservableCollection<Routing> Routes 
        {
            get
            {
                return routes;
            }

            set
            {
                if (value != routes)
                {
                    routes = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("Routes");
                }
            }
        }
        public MainWindow()
        {
            Routes = new ObservableCollection<Routing>();
            Routes.Add(new Routing { Product = "A", Quality = "C" });
            Routes.Add(new Routing { Product = "B", Quality = "D" });
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the Route object:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace Sandpit
{
    public class Routing : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private ObservableCollection<string> availableProducts;
        public ObservableCollection<string> AvailableProducts
        {
            get { return availableProducts; }
            set
            {
                if (availableProducts != value)
                {
                    availableProducts = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("AvailableProducts");
                }
            }
        }
        private string product;
        public string Product
        {
            get { return product; }
            set
            {
                if (product != value)
                {
                    product = value;
                    UpdateAvailableCosts();
                    OnPropertyChanged("Product");
                }
            }
        }
        private ObservableCollection<string> availableQuality;
        public ObservableCollection<string> AvailableQuality
        {
            get { return availableQuality; }
            set
            {
                if (availableQuality != value)
                {
                    availableQuality = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("AvailableQuality");
                }
            }
        }
        private string quality;
        public string Quality
        {
            get { return quality; }
            set
            {
                if (quality != value)
                {
                    quality = value;
                    UpdateAvailableCosts();
                    OnPropertyChanged("Quality");
                }
            }
        }

        //costs that are available to the user. These get updated when quality etc is changed
        private ObservableCollection<string> availableCosts;
        public ObservableCollection<string> AvailableCosts
        {
            get { return availableCosts; }
            set
            {
                if (availableCosts != value)
                {
                    availableCosts = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("AvailableCosts");
                }
            }
        }

        private string cost;
        public string Cost
        {
            get { return cost; }
            set
            {
                if (cost != value)
                {
                    cost = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Cost");
                }
            }
        }

        public void UpdateAvailableCosts()
        {
            //remove the old available options
            AvailableCosts.Clear();
            //populate it with just two items made up of the quality and cost for demo
            AvailableCosts.Add(Quality + Product);
            AvailableCosts.Add(Product + Quality);
            //make sure our current cost is in the list by just clearing it
            Cost = "";
        }

        public Routing()
        {
            AvailableProducts = new ObservableCollection<string> { "A", "B" };
            AvailableQuality = new ObservableCollection<string> { "C", "D" };
            AvailableCosts = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        }

        // Create the OnPropertyChanged method to raise the event
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Produces:

[image]

and changing things:

[image]

Works perfectly.

Comment: theres an error in the XAML,
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn Width="100" x:Name="Cost" Header="Cost" SelectedItem="{Binding Cost, Mode=TwoWay}" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableCosts}" />
SelectedItem isnt defined,maybe you meant SelectedValueBinding?
also the exception error is into the UpdateCost routine,it says AvailableCosts.Clear(); is null

Comment: Sorry, yes it's SelectedItemBinding with grid combo boxes. You'll want to create AvailableCosts in your constructor.

Comment: something like this? 
        public void UpdateCost()
        {
            //remove the old available options
            ObservableCollection<string> AvailableCosts = new ObservableCollection<string>();
            AvailableCosts.Clear();
            //add the new ones
            if (Quality == "high" && Operation == "stazione1")
            {
                AvailableCosts.Add("abc");
                AvailableCosts.Add("def");
            }
            //make sure our current cost is in the list by just making it the first one
            Cost = AvailableCosts[0];
        }

Comment: Now i managed to have a observablecollection which i can fill however i want,but still the combobox values are not getting added when i do Cost= AvailableCosts[0]

Comment: i think you misunderstood something. i dont want a cost to be selected when the user picks a value in a combobox,i actually need to populate the last combobox with the combination of the two values he choose before

Comment: I think I have misunderstood. Can you give an example of what the combobox should contain? So, I select Product "Wash" and quality "High", what do you want the combobox to allow for selection (and the selection to do)?

Comment: suppose the cost combobox is empty when i load the window. when i choose wash" and "high" i'd like to fill the cost combobox with 3 values,eg 1,2,3,which i will grab from the database as a string array or list. say instead i choose "wash" and "low", i would like the cost combobox to have 3 different values,say "4","5","6",still grabbed from db. Yesterday i noticed that your code "selects" a string from the strings already in the cost combobox,but doesnt fill it
i thought about declaring the cost as an observable collection inside the routing class, but i didnt have the chance to try it out

Comment: That was my understanding of what you were trying to do... The setting the cost = AvailableCosts[0] just picks the first of the things you've added based on quality and product. Taking your example, in the first case, you want to pick between 1,2,3, you have to reset it to something (in my example, 1, you could just but Cost="" to re-set to nothing). If you dont' set Cost when your AvailableCosts collection has changed, you could have them select "1", then change quality and it would be "1", with an available costs of "4","5","6", which doesn't make sense.

Comment: i just need to change the itemssource in the last combobox. ill probably end up using setter events on comboboxes if its not possible to do it with bindings.sucks because binding seems a lot more cleaner.

Comment: It's totally possible, I've done it before. I'm not sure why the code isn't working. It should. ItemsSourece of combobox is bound to AvailableCosts, which gets updated. I'll test it, just a sec.

Comment: yea it works perfectly now.could you explain briefly what was missing? did you change the xaml aswell? i see now that i just need to change values in the updatecost(),but i dont understand why you declare every field twice,once as a string and once as an observable collection

Comment: "once as a string and once as an observable collection"

That's because you need to bind the selection (we need to know which the user has selected) and the available selections (we need to give a list to the user to pick from).

You want to use comboboxes for all the fields, so we need the collections to actually provide the list in the combobox.

Comment: I did also change the xaml to something I'm more familiar with (using CellTemplate and CellEditingTemplate).

Comment: aaah i see now. ill play with the xaml a bit,see what i can be comfortable around :D thanks again